# Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. when debugging

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, codeblocks

If I debug my code then I get "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault." Here is my code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    struct term
    {
        char* name;
        long int id;
        float term_gpa;
    };
    struct term *term_ptr, student;

    term_ptr = &student;

    strcpy( term_ptr->name,"niton");
    term_ptr->id = 942044;
    term_ptr->term_gpa = 3.75;

    printf("Name : %s",term_ptr->name);
    printf("Name : %s",student.name);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error on line 17. Please help me! Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory for `term_ptr->name`

Comment: thanks, but if I change line 17 like this- term_ptr->name = "niton"; then no error occurs! Thanks again

Comment: If you do that you simply assign a string literal to your pointer. If you only mean to use term_ptr->name for reading that's ok. However, try to write something into it ... see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
strcpy( term_ptr->name,"niton");
```

to this:

```
term_ptr->name = strdup("niton");
```

Comment: No need to strdup a string literal unless you're going to free temp_ptr->name later.